# How to fetch value between second and third / from string (/ to be consider from right to left)

Tags: oracle11g

My requirement is to fetch the data between second and third '/' from a string(/ to be consider from right to left) and below are sample examples.

```
1.My string is RAM/ESH/BA/BU/MOR/SA and output to be derived is BU
2.My string is RAM/ESH/BA/MOR/SA and output to be derived is BA
3.My String is TR/IV/NI and  output to be derived is TR
```

Please help me query.

Comment: There is no "third" / in your last example. Do you mean / **or the beginning of the string**?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it - using only standard string functions (no regular expressions) for best performance. Notice the use of INSTR with -1 as the third parameter (indicating position); negative means start AND count from the end of the string (from right to left).

I added two more input strings to test for correct handling. If there is absolutely nothing between the second and third / from the right, the "token" must be NULL. Same if there aren't at least two / in the input string. As I explained in a Comment, you misstated the problem - you need at least two slashes in the input; if there are only two, you are taking the "token" from the beginning of the input string.

```
with
  inputs ( str ) as (
    select 'RAM/ESH/BA/BU/MOR/SA' from dual union all
    select 'RAM/ESH/BA/MOR/SA'    from dual union all
    select 'TR/IV/NI'             from dual union all
    select 'ST//TUL/SV'           from dual union all
    select 'MOR/SA'               from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select str,
       substr( str, instr(str, '/', -1, 3) + 1, 
                    instr(str, '/', -1, 2) - instr(str, '/', -1, 3) - 1
             ) as third_token_from_right
from   inputs;

STR                   THIRD_TOKEN_FROM_RIGHT
--------------------  ----------------------
RAM/ESH/BA/BU/MOR/SA  BU
RAM/ESH/BA/MOR/SA     BA
TR/IV/NI              TR
ST//TUL/SV  
MOR/SA
```